# How to replace "Update" button by "Save" and "Cancel" buttons in a Ruby on Rails application with "form_with" form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-helpers

I am using a form in a rails application in order to update a record.

```
<%= form_with model: @article do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But I don't want only one "Update" button, I would like 2 buttons (Save and Cancel). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

For a Cancel button, you could use a `link_to` to redirect to a different page.

`<%= link_to 'Cancel', preferred_redirect_path %>`

To change the text for the `submit` you can use the following.

`<%= f.submit "Custom Text" %>`